# Is there any other way to write the Watch function in Gulp, I was trying to execute a command in gulp but its showing errors

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to install the node.js. The installation process was successful.
But when I'm running `gulp` command in terminal I'm getting this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Gayatree\test-widget> gulp
[15:32:28] Using gulpfile ~\test-widget\gulpfile.js
[15:32:28] Starting 'default'...
[15:32:28] Starting 'build'...   
[15:32:28] Starting 'compress'...
[15:32:28] Starting 'clean'...   
[15:32:28] Finished 'clean' after 23 ms
[15:32:28] Starting '<anonymous>'...   
[15:32:29] Finished '<anonymous>' after 127 ms
[15:32:29] Finished 'compress' after 157 ms
[15:32:29] Finished 'build' after 165 ms
[15:32:29] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[15:32:29] '<anonymous>' errored after 3.01 ms
[15:32:29] Error: watching ./src/**/***: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by 
using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
at Gulp.watch (C:\Users\Gayatree\test-widget\node_modules\gulp\index.js:31:11)        
at C:\Users\Gayatree\test-widget\gulpfile.js:47:14
at bound (domain.js:419:14)
at runBound (domain.js:432:12)
at asyncRunner (C:\Users\Gayatree\test-widget\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18) 
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11)
[15:32:29] 'default' errored after 377 ms
PS C:\Users\Gayatree\test-widget>
```

I saw in some websites where it says to change the format of writting the `watch` fucntion and I tried also but it didn't work.
The page where its showing the error is given below.

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
zip = require("gulp-zip"),
del = require("del"),
newer = require("gulp-newer"),
log = require('fancy-log'),
colors = require('ansi-colors'), 
plumber = require("gulp-plumber"),
gulpif = require("gulp-if"),
jsonTransform = require("gulp-json-transform"),
intercept = require("gulp-intercept"),
argv = require("yargs").argv,
widgetBuilderHelper = require("widgetbuilder-gulp-helper"),
jsValidate = require("gulp-jsvalidate");

var pkg = require("./package.json"),
paths = widgetBuilderHelper.generatePaths(pkg),
xmlversion = widgetBuilderHelper.xmlversion;

gulp.task("clean", function () {
    return del([
        paths.WIDGET_TEST_DEST,
        paths.WIDGET_DIST_DEST
    ], { force: true });
});

gulp.task("compress", gulp.series(["clean"], function () {
    return gulp.src("src/**/*")
        .pipe(zip(pkg.name + ".mpk"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.TEST_WIDGETS_FOLDER))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
}));

gulp.task("build", gulp.series(["compress"]));

gulp.task("default", gulp.series(['build'], function() {
    gulp.watch("./src/**/*", ["compress"]);
    gulp.watch("./src/**/*.js", ["copy:js"]);
    gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", ["copy:html"])
}));

gulp.task("compress", gulp.series(["clean"], function () {
    return gulp.src("src/**/*")
        .pipe(zip(pkg.name + ".mpk"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.TEST_WIDGETS_FOLDER))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
}));

gulp.task("copy:js", function () {
    return gulp.src(["./src/**/*.js"])
        .pipe(plumber(function (error) {
            var msg = colors.red("Error");
            if (error.fileName) {
                msg += colors.red(" in ") + colors.cyan(error.fileName);
            }
            msg += " : " + colors.cyan(error.message);
            log(msg);
            this.emit("end");
        }))
        .pipe(jsValidate())
        .pipe(newer(paths.TEST_WIDGETS_DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.TEST_WIDGETS_DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER));
});

gulp.task("copy:html", function () {
    return gulp.src(["./src/**/*.html"])
        .pipe(newer(paths.TEST_WIDGETS_DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.TEST_WIDGETS_DEPLOYMENT_FOLDER));
});

gulp.task("version:xml", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.PACKAGE_XML)
        .pipe(xmlversion(argv.n))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./src/"));
});

gulp.task("version:json", function () {
    return gulp.src("./package.json")
        .pipe(gulpif(typeof argv.n !== "undefined", jsonTransform(function(data) {
            data.version = argv.n;
            return data;
        }, 2)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});

gulp.task("icon", function (cb) {
    var icon = (typeof argv.file !== "undefined") ? argv.file : "./icon.png";
    console.log("\nUsing this file to create a base64 string: " + colors.cyan(icon));
    gulp.src(icon)
        .pipe(intercept(function (file) {
            console.log("\nCopy the following to your " + pkg.name + ".xml (after description):\n\n" + colors.cyan("<icon>") + file.contents.toString("base64") + colors.cyan("<\/icon>") + "\n");
            cb();
        }));
});

gulp.task("folders", function () {
    paths.showPaths(); return;
});

gulp.task("modeler", function (cb) {
    widgetBuilderHelper.runmodeler(MODELER_PATH, MODELER_ARGS, paths.TEST_PATH, cb);
});

gulp.task("version", gulp.parallel(["version:xml", "version:json"]));
```

Can Someone help me to debug this code? I have checked the codes but I couldn't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **many** lines of code that look like this:

`gulp.parallel(["version:xml", "version:json"])`

and

`gulp.task("compress", gulp.series(["clean"], function () {`

Change them all to be of the form:

`gulp.parallel("version:xml", "version:json")`

and

`gulp.task("compress", gulp.series("clean", function () {`

`series` and `parallel` do not take an array as an argument.  See https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series#parameters

Change these as well, from

```
gulp.watch("./src/**/*", ["compress"]);
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.js", ["copy:js"]);
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", ["copy:html"])
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", ["copy:html"])
```

to

```
gulp.watch("./src/**/*", gulp.series("compress"));
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.js", gulp.series("copy:js"));
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", gulp.series("copy:html"))
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", gulp.series("copy:html"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did change all the ``Series`` function and ``parallel`` function but still it showing the same error. Can you help me a little more Sir?

Comment: See additional info in the answer above.

Comment: No there is no changes in terminal.